# Automatically plot different colored lines

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot several kernel density estimations on the same graph, and I want them to all be different colors. I have a kludged solution using a string `'rgbcmyk'` and stepping through it for each separate plot, but I start having duplicates after 7 iterations. Is there an easier/more efficient way to do this, and with more color options?

```
for n=1:10
 source(n).data=normrnd(rand()*100,abs(rand()*50),100,1); %generate random data
end
cstring='rgbcmyk'; % color string
figure
hold on
for n=1:length(source)
 [f,x]=ksdensity(source(n).data); % calculate the distribution
 plot(x,f,cstring(mod(n,7)+1))  % plot with a different color each time
end
```

Comment: Did you try simply doing "hold all"? That automatically draws news colors for each new plot command.

Comment: "hold all" is not an answer to the actual question, but may be a solution to many people ending here because a mere "hold on" draws all the curves in blue. Many Thank to @twerdster !

Comment: As of **R2014b**, the usual `hold on` is _functionally equivalent_ to `hold all`.  However, the question of how to get more than the 7 default colors remains.  A default color map may be a solution as described by Azim or a function to generate colors tuned for easy visual discrimination can be used, [as below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22029354/2778484).

Comment: When I use `hold all` I get plots in different colors (even though I must say they look pretty dull), whereas when I use `hold on`, all my plots become blue. So I wonder what functional equivalence is.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye `hold on` merely prevents MATLAB from erasing the previous plots when making a new `plot` call. `hold all` assigns new attributes to subsequent calls to plot as well.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye In R2014b and newer,`hold on` gives different color plots.  You're using and older version.  From [the current docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html), "`hold all` is the same as `hold on`. **Note:**   This syntax will be removed in a future release. Use `hold on` instead."  See also [the release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#bugqj34-1).

Comment: @HelloGoodbye The only case when the previous behavior would take place is if `graphicsversion('handlegraphics')` returns `true`, indicating MATLAB is running with the old handle graphics system.

Comment: @chappjc Ah! Thanks! Yes, my Matlab version may not be the newest.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You could use a colormap such as HSV to generate a set of colors. For example:

```
cc=hsv(12);
figure; 
hold on;
for i=1:12
    plot([0 1],[0 i],'color',cc(i,:));
end
```

MATLAB has 13 different named colormaps (*'doc colormap'* lists them all).

Another option for plotting lines in different colors is to use the *LineStyleOrder* property; see [Defining the Color of Lines for Plotting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/bqsxy_a-1.html) in the MATLAB documentation for more information.

Comment: For posterity's sake, I chose to accept this answer over @Mark Elliot's `hold all` solution due to its versatility of being able to choose different color maps.

Comment: How can I make it to work using "line" plot command instead of plot ?

Answer (score 108):

Actually, a decent shortcut method for getting the colors to cycle is to use `hold all;` in place of `hold on;`.  Each successive `plot` will rotate (automatically for you) through MATLAB's default colormap.

From the MATLAB site on [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html):

> `hold all` holds the plot and the current line color and line style so that subsequent plotting commands do not reset the ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder property values to the beginning of the list. Plotting commands continue cycling through the predefined colors and linestyles from where the last plot stopped in the list.

Answer (score 38):

Late answer, but two things to add:

- For information on how to change the `'ColorOrder'` property and how to set a global default with `'DefaultAxesColorOrder'`, see the "Appendix" at the bottom of this post.
- There is a great tool on the MATLAB Central File Exchange to generate any number of visually distinct colors, if you have the Image Processing Toolbox to use it.  Read on for details.

---

The [`ColorOrder` `axes` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#ColorOrder) allows MATLAB to automatically cycle through a list of colors when using `hold on/all` (again, see Appendix below for how to `set`/`get` the `ColorOrder` for a specific axis or globally via `DefaultAxesColorOrder`). However, by default **MATLAB only specifies a short list of colors (*just 7* as of R2013b)** to cycle through, and on the other hand it can be problematic to find a good set of colors for more data series. For 10 plots, you obviously cannot rely on the default `ColorOrder`.

A great way to **define N visually distinct colors** is with the ["Generate Maximally Perceptually-Distinct Colors" (GMPDC) submission on the MATLAB Central File File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors).  It is best described in the author's own words:

> This function generates a set of colors which are distinguishable by reference to the ["Lab" color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space), which more closely matches human color perception than RGB. Given an initial large list of possible colors, it iteratively chooses the entry in the list that is farthest (in Lab space) from all previously-chosen entries.

For example, when 25 colors are requested:

[image: 25 "maximally perceptually-distinct colors"]

The GMPDC submission was chosen on MathWorks' official blog as [Pick of the Week](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/12/23/generate-distinct-colors-for-your-matlab-plots/) in 2010 in part because of the ability to request an arbitrary number of colors (in contrast to MATLAB's built in 7 default colors).  They even made the excellent suggestion to set MATLAB's `ColorOrder` on startup to,

```
distinguishable_colors(20)
```

Of course, you can set the `ColorOrder` for a single axis or simply generate a list of colors to use in any way you like.  For example, to generate 10 "maximally perceptually-distinct colors" and use them for 10 plots on the same axis (**but not using `ColorOrder`, thus requiring a loop**):

```
% Starting with X of size N-by-P-by-2, where P is number of plots
mpdc10 = distinguishable_colors(10) % 10x3 color list
hold on
for ii=1:size(X,2),
    plot(X(:,ii,1),X(:,ii,2),'.','Color',mpdc10(ii,:));
end
```

The process is simplified, **requiring no `for` loop, with the `ColorOrder` axis property**:

```
% X of size N-by-P-by-2
mpdc10 = distinguishable_colors(10)
ha = axes; hold(ha,'on')
set(ha,'ColorOrder',mpdc10)    % --- set ColorOrder HERE ---
plot(X(:,:,1),X(:,:,2),'-.')   % loop NOT needed, 'Color' NOT needed. Yay!
```

**APPENDIX**

To get the `ColorOrder` RGB array used for the current axis,

```
get(gca,'ColorOrder')
```

To get the default `ColorOrder` for new axes,

```
get(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder')
```

Example of setting new global `ColorOrder` with 10 colors on MATLAB start, in `startup.m`:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',distinguishable_colors(10))
```

Answer (score 13):

Late to the party. I was looking into this myself and just found about this axes option called ColorOrder
you can specify the colour order for the session or just for the figure and then just plot an array and let MATLAB automatically cycle through the colours specified.

see [Changing the Default ColorOrder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/bqsxy_a-1.html)

example

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',jet(5))
A=rand(10,5);
plot(A);
```

Comment: For a one-off axis: `set(gca,'ColorOrder',jet(5));`

Comment: excellent just for informing about jet(number) which doesn't require any fancy toolboxes

Answer (score 5):

If all vectors have equal size, create a matrix and plot it.
Each column is plotted with a  different color automatically
Then you can use `legend` to indicate columns:

```
data = randn(100, 5);

figure;
plot(data);

legend(cellstr(num2str((1:size(data,2))')))
```

Or, if you have a cell with kernels names, use

```
legend(names)
```