# MATLAB Plotting multiple lines with different ledgends/colours on same graph

Tags: matlab, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically plot different colored lines in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028818/automatically-plot-different-colored-lines-in-matlab)

I have the following data

```
X <25x139 double>
t <25x1 double>
names <139x1 cell>
```

So essentially t is time, and X is a matrix of 139 different samples at each time interval, where names is an array of each of those sample names.

I want to plot (on the same axis) a range of my samples against time, where each line has

a) A different color

b) A legend name

Comment: This has been covered a number of times in other questions. For plotting different colored lines: [Automatically plot different colored lines in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2028818/52738), [Matlab choose random color for plotting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3225206/52738)... For dealing with legends, look through what you get from [this SO search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[matlab]+legend), or check the [LEGEND documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html).

Comment: @ash: a warning: at 139 samples, you will have a really hard time finding that many visually distinguishable colors, plus the legend will be huge with 139 entries..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this work?

```
plot(t,X);legend(names);
```

Comment: That's great - I'd been messing around with for loops and cmaps.