# How can I create a colormap with many visually distinct colors?

Tags: matlab, colormap

### Difference from proposed duplicate

[Matlab choose random color for plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225206/matlab-choose-random-color-for-plotting) asks how to create a colormap with **randomly** selected colors. I am asking how to choose **visually distinct** colors for a colormap. Randomly selected colors are not guaranteed to be visually distinctive. In fact, I use random colors as a counter example in my question.

If my question is going to be a duplicate, it should be a duplicate of [Automatically plot different colored lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028818/automatically-plot-different-colored-lines/) because at least [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028818/automatically-plot-different-colored-lines/22029354#22029354), answers my question about visually distinct colors even though the question does not ask for that detail. But **none** of the answers of [Matlab choose random color for plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225206/matlab-choose-random-color-for-plotting) are helpful, so don't use that one!

---

### Original Question

The `lines` colormap alternates 7 colors that are visually distinct in a predefined order. `flag` and `prism` do this also. The colors repeat after 7 distinct colors for `lines`, 6 for `prism` and 4 for `flag`.

These colormaps are very useful for distinguishing between labeled segments in an image because labels often have consecutive values which have low visual distinctness in the `jet` or `parula` colorspaces.

For example, using the first image from the [NYUv2 dataset](http://cs.nyu.edu/~silberman/datasets/nyu_depth_v2.html), you can see that dishwasher and counter have almost the same color using `colormap('parula')`

[image: Image segments colored with parula]

It gets better for dishwasher and counter using `colormap('lines')`, but worse for chair and trashcan, because the value of trashcan is 12 and chair is 5. 12 mod 7 = 5, so they get the same color assignment

[image: Image segments colored with lines]

I have *n* labels, so I would like to define a colormap that has *n* alternating visually distinct colors. Then, I can avoid the problem of two labels sharing the same modulus.

I know how to create a custom colormap, but the challenge is making the colors visually distinct. One thing I tried is randomly sampling colors from jet (similar to the solutions suggested to [Matlab choose random color for plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225206/matlab-choose-random-color-for-plotting)).

```
c_jet = colormap('jet');
idx = randperm(size(c_jet, 1));
c_new = c_jet(idx(1:30),:);
colormap(c_new);
```

But the colors are not visually distinct enough. The ceiling and the wall are practically identical.

[image: Image segments colored with random sample from jet]

It may be the case that 30 distinct colors is simply too many to ask for, but I'd like a general approach that gets as close as possible.

Comment: Do you mean `colormap(parula(7))`? Each colormap is a function that takes and argument.

Comment: That works for numbers < 10, but the colors are not distinctive enough for larger numbers. I would like a way of generating a color map that has n colors where you would be unlikely to confuse one color for another if you were looking at a legend for example.

Comment: Maybe https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors could help you

Comment: @jodag Nice! I'll try that out.

Comment: @jodag The file exchange code works perfectly. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @Cecilia Good to hear. I created an answer.

Comment: @Shai I've edited the question to clarify why it is not a duplicate, but it's been sitting on the reopen queue for several days with only 4 votes. Would you please reconsider your (deciding) close vote?

Answer (score 1):

For example from wikipedia you can get a list of distinguishable colors

[Help:Distinguishable colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Distinguishable_colors)

The references contain a link to a stackexchange thread where you can read more.

With theses colors you can build your own colormap.