# Setting colors for plot function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I would like to be able to choose the colors for a multiline plot but I can not get it. This is my code

```
colors = {'b','r','g'};
T = [0 1 2]';
column = [2 3];
count = magic(3);
SelecY = count(:,column),
plot(T,SelecY,'Color',colors{column});
```

Comment: Also check out this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028818/automatically-plot-different-colored-lines-in-matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only specify one color at a time that way, and it must be specified as a 3-element RGB vector. Your three routes are:

1. Loop through and specify the colors by string, like you have them:

   ```
   hold on
   for i=1:size(SelecY, 2)
       plot(T, SelecY(:,i), colors{i});
   end
   ```
2. Using the RGB color specification, you can pass the colors in via the 'Color' property, like you were trying to do above:

   ```
   cols = jet(8);
   hold on
   for i=1:size(SelecY, 2)
       plot(T, SelecY(:,i), 'Color', cols(i,:));
   end
   ```
3. Also using the RGB way, you can specify the `ColorOrder` up front, and then let matlab cycle through:

   ```
   set(gca, 'ColorOrder', jet(3))
   hold all
   for i=1:size(SelecY, 2)
       plot(T, SelecY(:,i));
   end
   ```

For setting colors *after* the fact, see the other answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your multiple answers.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason I couldn't get it to work without using a handle, but:

```
h = plot(T,SelecY);
set(h, {'Color'}, colors(column)');
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems to be the most compact and straightforward one.