# Cycle over colors while plotting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

When I plot several curves on the same plot using `hold on`, each curve defaults to the same color (blue). I'd like them to have all different colors.

One solution I've seen is to make a color vector, e.g. `c = ['k', 'g', 'r', ...]` and loop over it, but I don't like this solution. Things will break if my number of plots is greater than the length of my color vector `c`, and I don't want to have to define `c` in every file.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically plot different colored lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028818/automatically-plot-different-colored-lines)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `hold all` instead. Your curves should cycle over the colormap automatically. From [`help hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html):

> hold all holds the graph and the current line color and line style so
>   that subsequent plotting commands do not reset the ColorOrder and
>   LineStyleOrder property values to the beginning of the list. Plotting
>   commands continue cycling through the predefined colors and line
>   styles from where the last graph stopped in the list.

You can examine the colormap with `get(gca,'ColorOrder')`.

Comment: Excellent, I knew that there had to be a simple solution.

Comment: From the same page: "hold all is the same as hold on.
Note:   This syntax will be removed in a future release. Use hold on instead."

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the default `'ColorOrder'` property on the global environment doing:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',hsv(10))
```

where I replaced the default colors for a set of 10 colors given by `hsv` colormap. Of course, you can also place any other set of colors using either one the colormap color generators (`hsv`,`hot`,`cooper`,`lines`, ..., use `doc colormap` for more details ), as I did before, or just placing any n x 3 matrix.
In case you want to use the list of colors: {black, green, red} for the current axis you would do:

```
set( gca,'ColorOrder', [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 1 0] )
```