# Change line colors after plotting

Tags: matlab, plot, colormap

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028818/automatically-plot-different-colored-lines), i've plotted a matrix of signals `t` (m by 1) and `x` (m by n):

```
 plot(t,x);
```

and, after that, i am wishing to apply a coloured scheme on colormap matrix `c` (n by 3). How to do it?

**EDIT**
Trivially, and ignoring *most* -if not all- performance etiquette, through a `for` call you can set colours *while* building a plot, plotting each column inside the loop, and setting/applying the colormap 'on the fly', just as suggested by the pointed post, but which is *not* the question:

```
for i=1:n
    plot(t(:,1),x(:,i),'Color',c(i,:));
    hold on;
end
```

This is pseudocode which *will not* run if you don't have `t`, `x` and `c` defined. 
Data, and the code shown here, cooked, just ready for you:

```
load spectra.mat; 
x=NIR'; m=size(x,1);n=size(x,2);
t=900+2*(1:m)'; %Don't question this :)...
c=winter(n);
for i=1:n
    plot(t(:,1),x(:,i),'Color',c(i,:));
    hold on;
end
title('Near Infrarred Spectra for Gasoline Samples');
xlabel('Wavelength [nm]');
ylabel('Infrarred Spectral Magnitude [lm^2/nm]');
```

or without the `for`, better:

```
load spectra.mat; 
x=NIR'; m=size(x,1);n=size(x,2);
t=900+2*(1:m)'; %Don't question this :)...
c=winter(n);
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',c);
plot(t,x);
title('Near Infrarred Spectra for Gasoline Samples');
xlabel('Wavelength [nm]');
ylabel('Infrarred Spectral Magnitude [lm^2/nm]');
```

[image: Spectral example].

All them unfortunately *prior* the plotting. Never after...

Comment: The problem is explained. I am truly, positive clear that no data nor further code is required, if you are used to MATLAB. If there were a trivial solution i wouldnt be asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "All them unfurtunately prior the plotting. Never after..." ? I have tried both versions of your code with a dummy `NIR` and it works just fine.

Comment: The code works fine, but the OP wants to first plot the lines, _then_ change their colors. I think this would require iterating over the Lineseries objects one by one.

Comment: @Tamás. The question is to change colours of plotted lines. Already plotted lines. Plot could come from a plotting function, or existing | compiled code. Or from existing FIG files. Whatever, after the `plot` command was already commited.
@Naveh. Lineseries iteration could be the only solution i see AFAIK too. Maybe there is a solution in the MExchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21102-cmapline) function (CMAPLINE):

```
plot(t,x,':o');
cmapline('colormap',c);
```

Which solves the issue. Thanks for the comments, buddies.

hypfco.