# Vectorize plotting multiple lines with different colors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to vectorize/accelerate the task of plotting multiple lines with different colors?

The working-but-slow approach is

```
X = [1 2; 3 4];
Y = [2 -4; 5 2];
figure;
hold on;
colors = [1 0 0; 0 1 0];
for idx = 1:size(X, 2)
    l = plot(X(:, idx), Y(:, idx), 'Color', colors(idx, :));
end
hold off;
```

I tried

```
X = [1 2; 3 4];
Y = [2 -4; 5 2];
figure;
plot(X, Y, 'Color', [1 0 0; 0 1 0]);
```

but no luck.

Comment: Can't test right now but maybe you can try setting axis limits manually once before plotting so that Matlab does not need to figure every time if it needs to re-calculate them; check [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-performance) article by Yahir Altman and a few tips in the commentary below the text. Hope that helps somehow!

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22029354/2778484

Comment: One known improvement: use low-level function `line` over `plot`.

Comment: Hey @chappjc, you should come here more often :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably too hacky to be a useful replacement of the loop, but here it goes:

```
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', [1 0 0; 0 1 0], 'NextPlot', 'add')
plot(X, Y);
```

The `'ColorOrder'` property contains the colors to be used by default for new plots. Setting `'NextPlot'` to `'add'` seems to be necessary so that the call to `plot` doesn't reset `'ColorOrder'` to its default value.

Tested on R2015b.

Comment: +1; thanks! Wondering if this would really make things faster? My ultimate goal is to accelerate things (not just vectorizing) :-D

Comment: @SibbsGambling Not sure about speed, better try in your Matlab version and specific case. But the loop is much more readable; I'd probably go with that

Comment: Oh but what if my colors are RGBA instead of RGB? Just tried -- `set(gca, 'ColorOrder', colors);` doesn't really take in four columns.

Comment: @SibbsGambling Matlab doesn't support alpha as part of the color specifcation, as fas as I know. You can specify the alpha of a graphic object separately. But that doesn't work for `plot`; only for `surface` etc. So you probably need to do the alpha computation by hand to convert to RGB colors